# In Android can I do a sql query on a cursor?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I might have more then one filter being chosen on my database, so I would like to query the database for a cursor, then do a query on that cursor to return another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do a query on a cursor.  A cursor is the result of a query.  It is not the source of a query.  You need to do a new query for the same place you got the original cursor, with new arguments that specify the new data set you want.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use inner loop for filter record it is one of the option for you

for that you have to first fetch record in cursor1 and in a inner loop you can use value of 1st Cursor and query again for cursor2

**EDIT**

1) If you want particular columns then You can filter in db.query() method
**for example**

```
Cursor curTaskList = db.query("tablename", new String[]{"col1", "col2"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

2) If you want Particular row then you can filter in db.query() method 
**for example**

```
Cursor curTaskList = db.query("timebasedlist", null, "col1 = ? AND col2 = ?", new String[]{"val1", "val2"}, null, null, null);
```

so there is no need for query over cursor

You can filter within a single query

If your cursor has more than one row you can fetch row by row using loop

Comment: You can have several cursors open at the same time. You can "fetch" from any open cursor at any point in your program logic.

Comment: so how do I do a query on cursor 1?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the query as text and use them to create new cursors?

Comment: I'm not understanding the flow of how that would work? Query a cursor, save as text, parse text, convert to cursor?

Comment: Yep, just like that.  So you'd have one loop that creates the cursor that looks for the filters, and in that loop, you'd read the filter, use it create a second cursor based on that, do your record reading, and then come back to the first loop to get the next filter and so on.